# How to get the total MB size of all media data using Telethon

Tags: web-scraping, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

As the title says, how do I get the total MB size of all media data (photos, videos, ect.) from a Telegram Channel using Telethon?

I figured out I could use `data = await client(functions.messages.SearchRequest(...))` to get the data of a channel, but it seems like when I try to strip the data with `data.media.document.size`, it only gets the sizes of some media files, and not all? How do I get for all media types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`client.iter_messages`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages) you can then get the [`Message.file`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.file) which has a [`File.size`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.file.File.size). In v1:

```py
total_size = 0
async for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
    if message.file:
        total_size += message.file.size
        print('current total:', total_size)
```